# How to convert python3 program into python2.7 program

Tags: python

I use jetson nano board testing program carried out following this instruction can run at python3 interpreter, but in python2.7 version of the interpreter will prompt an error, I would like to ask you, how to modify it?

```
  import time
  import struct
  from binascii import unhexlify
  import binascii
  import crcmod

  import math
  byte0 = b'\x01'
  byte1 = b'\xEA'

  DEC1 = int(100)
  DEC2 = int(20)
  byte2 =(struct.pack("i",DEC1)[-4:-3])#线速度
  byte3 =(struct.pack("i",DEC1)[-3:-2])#线速度
  #        speed_vel = byte2 + byte3
  byte4 = (struct.pack("i",DEC2)[-4:-3])    #角速度两个字节
  byte5 = (struct.pack("i",DEC2)[-3:-2])
  #        speed_ang = byte4+byte5
  byte_speed = byte2 + byte3 + byte4 + byte5
  read = byte0 + byte1 + byte_speed  #解析校验码要输入的前几位
  read=(str(binascii.b2a_hex(read))[2:-1])
  crc16 =crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x18005, rev=True, initCrc=0xFFFF, xorOut=0x0000)
  data = read.replace(" ","")
  readcrcout=hex(crc16(unhexlify(data))).upper()
  print(readcrcout)
  str_list = list(readcrcout)
  if len(str_list) < 6:
    str_list.insert(2, '0'*(6-len(str_list)))  # 位数不足补0
  crc_data = "".join(str_list)
  #print(crc_data)
  read = read.strip()+crc_data[4:]+crc_data[2:4]
  read = bytes.fromhex(read)
  speed_code = read
  print('speed_code', speed_code)
```

Comment: Do you have a description of the error?

Comment: Why can't you install Python 3 on the Jetson Nano board? Python 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: Try running your Python 2 on an XT PC. Jokes aside, why would you want to run on 2.7 in the first place? Can you share exactly what version of 2.7 if you absolutely must use it, and share the error message? The `print()` seems immediately suspect

Comment: readcrcout=hex(crc16(unhexlify(data))).upper()
This command can't run, I also want to run it in python3 environment, but some packages can't support it and only rely on python2.7, so I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: I want to know how to configure jetson nano in the python3 environment and what version of the source code package to use to solve the dependency on python2.7 version?